# Jackson Converter for Retrofit in Kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, jackson, retrofit

Hello awesome community.

I ended up here after looking all over the places (here & others) about something that is supposed to be simple. More precisely, I am replacing `GSON` library with `Jackson` for some reasons.

Basically, what bugs me the most, is that my `Jackson Converter` seems to be ignored by `Retrofit` or something.

What I tried :

```
private val retrofit: Retrofit by lazy {
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .addConverterFactory(
            JacksonConverterFactory.create(jackson)
        )
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .client(httpClient)
        .build()
}
```

where `jackson` is also part of this `ApiClient` that I am writing

```
private val jackson: ObjectMapper by lazy {
    ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(jacksonKotlinModule)
        .setDateFormat(
            SimpleDateFormat(
                "yyyy-MM-dd",
                Locale.getDefault()
            )
        )
}
```

and, of course `jacksonKotlinModule`

```
private val jacksonKotlinModule: KotlinModule by lazy {
    KotlinModule.Builder()
        .configure(KotlinFeature.StrictNullChecks, true)
        .build()
}
```

All of this in my attempt to get an error when Kotlin `non-null` fields of a POJO receives a `null` value from the response of an end-point.

On top of this, I tried the way found in every tutorials about `Jackson & Kotlin` which is just using `jacksonObjectMapper()` method available in `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin`

Why am I saying that `seems to be ignored` is because 2 reasons, neither I get any errors or warning or even crashes when I get `null` response for a `non-null` Object, neither any `Date` field isn't formatted as per the `DateFormatter` that I provided.

It does feel like I might have missed something along the way..
What could I do this in other ways?
Oh, I've also tried `@JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd")` on a specific field, without success

Later edit:
Looks like after more investigations, retrofit does not completely ignore the date format I am providing, but it adapts it somehow. For example
`"date":"2022-08-24T13:23:10Z"` and with `SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")` it parses the date for `year`, `month`, `day` but also adds `00` for others.. Output is: `Wed Aug 24 00:00:00 GTM+03:00 2022`

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `@JsonProperty` annotation before all your properties in classes that you are parsing JSON to? I think that you might be missing it and that's why it doesn't work.

When you are using OkHttp directly you can specify to use `jacksonObjectMapper()` which uses jackson kotlin module. You can't do that when  building Retrofit object as `addConverterFactory()` method takes Converter.Factory type and `jacksonObjectMapper()` returns `ObjectMapper`, not a factory. That's why you have to add `@JsonProperty` before every field.

I think it would be quite simple to create your own class that extends Converter.Factory but returns ObjectMapper with kotlin module added.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the time took. Yes, I've added all the properties (since I switched from `GSON` which had the `@SerializedName()` annotation, I've had to change them all with `@JsonProperty`. On top of that I've also tried `@JsonFormat`. 
About the custom `Factory`, you think I should ? Seemed pretty straight forwart the implementation using `KotlinModule.Builder` registred to the `ObjectMapper` (actually, that's what `jacksonObjectMapper()` does behind as I've checked. Also, see my `Later edit` part (which I didn't notice at the beginning)